# How to distinguish Jenkins credentials

Tags: jenkins

Using Jenkins to create a freestyle project, when setting the repositories it asks to specify from Credentials, just like the following image shows.
[image: Credentials]

But how do people distinguish these credentials from all stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its normally distinct using combination of `Username` & `Description` provided during creation of credential

[image: creation]

In the dropdown it will appear as follows

[image: testing]

Comment: @ShiheZhang no problem. Remember to upvote and mark answer as accepted, if it was useful, so that others can benefit too

Answer (score 0):

If access through items menu, click the small hidden triangle beside job name (you need to hover near the name to show the hidden triangle) will show `Credentials` action 
 [image]

Or access the left menu `Credential` option after clicking the job name

[image]

Will lead to the same page. These credentials page is different from `System Config` -> `Credentials` is the credentials only for that job. Normally the `ID` will help you to distinguish the credentials, however, sometimes people (like me) didn't know it works this way. Then Jenkins would generate a random meaningless string to identify them, which can't help normal human to separate them with certainty.
[image]

After clicking the link in `Domain` column, the description will be shown there, and you can also update it from that page.